# Change number of workspaces in ubuntu 12.04LTS to just one?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-2d

I am new to using ubuntu. I am running ubuntu 12.04LTS in VmWare. By default I see multiple copies(3) of Desktop/workspaces when I login to ubuntu using my user account. This is making my system really slow and often cause it to hang sometimes. Can someone please suggest the steps to turn off this multiple workspace feature so that I see only one desktop like it is seen in MS windows. I looked up for help previous posts on ask ubuntu forum but didn't understand properly how this issue can be resolved. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry,sorry, I will look into 12.04, will get back to you.

Comment: I read your comment to Sylvain's post. I will give it some thought and try some more things tomorrow. It should be possible of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unity2D

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following command:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t integer /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces 1
```

To restore the default 4 viewports:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t integer /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces 4
```

### Unity3D

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following commands:

```
gconftool -t int -s /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize 1
gconftool -t int -s /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/vsize 1
```

To restore the default 4 workspaces:

```
gconftool -t int -s /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize 2
gconftool -t int -s /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/vsize 2
```

Comment: the commands you suggested run fine on the terminal but it has not changed the number of desktops/workspaces :( . What can I do?

Comment: @SwatiRathi Are you running unity-2D?

Comment: Yes I am...Is that a cause of problem??

Comment: Unity 3D is not supported on my system ... I just checked!

Comment: @SwatiRathi I've updated my answer for unity 2D. Please try the first command.

Comment: I tried the command for unity 2D...It made no difference :(...still getting multiple desktops!

Comment: @SwatiRathi Please try with gconftool-2

Comment: @Sylvain using gconftool-2 did not help.. :(

Comment: @ Jacob I am running unity 2d can your suggested command help me...I read somewhere that on unity 3d we have compiz and on unity 2d we have metacity...Also @Sylvain also pointed out the same..

Comment: @SwatiRathi Sylvain's commands work perfectly on my 12.04 (VM), Unity 2d.. after log out/in. Did you log out/in?

Comment: Yes I did logout then logged in again to see the effect of change..

Comment: @jacob did you execute the command as a root or as a unprivileged user?

Comment: just as "normal" user (well, normal is subjective :) ). Not as guest by the way.

Comment: @Jacob Even I am running it as normal user. I wonder what the issue might be!! Sylvain's commands seems to be correct for this problem but I don't understand why the problem could not be resolved for me :(( . It's still an open question for me please feel free to suggest some alternative solutions. Sylvain and Jacob thanks for your help anyways :)